# What is the issue with this random int generator in java?

Tags: java, methods

I have tried to develop a program in which a random number generator will develop a number, then depending on the number chosen, one of the members of a pre-defined array will be printed.(I want the method to be invoked inside the array index number)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Testing{
public static void main(String args[]){
public static int calculatew () {
    Random generator = new Random();  
    int number1 = generator.nextInt(3);
}
String array1 [] = new String[4];
array1[1]="Tom";
array1[2]="Jerry";
array1[3]="Mike";
array1[0]="Dustin";
System.out.println("the very first name is "+array1[calculatew]+" The second name is "+array1[calculatew]+" the third accodental name is "+array1[calculatew]+" and the final random name is "+array1[calculatew]+".");

}
}
```

When the program is being compiled it gives me back the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
Syntax error on token "int", @ expected
calculatew cannot be resolved to a variable
calculatew cannot be resolved to a variable
calculatew cannot be resolved to a variable
calculatew cannot be resolved to a variable

at Testing.main(Testing.java:7)
```

Would someone please tell me what the main problem is with this program.

Thank you so much for your answers in advance

Comment: One of the benefits of being strict about indenting your code is that your mistakes become easier to spot. That's a hint.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
public static int calculatew () {
    Random generator = new Random();  
    int number1 = generator.nextInt(3);
}
```

move method outside main

```
public static void main(String args[]){
 int calcResults = calculatew ();
....
}
public static int calculatew () {
    Random generator = new Random();  
    int number1 = generator.nextInt(3);
    return number1;
}
```

Comment: he should also invoke it with `()`

Comment: and the method needs to return an int...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the already posted answers about how to call a method, calculatew creates a new Random instance each time it is called. Random is initialized off the time of day, so you may get several identical results.

It would be better to make generator a static field in your class, initialized once when the class is loaded. Then the series of nextInt calls will actually get a series of numbers generated by its algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define method inside method. You should define calculatew() method outside of the main() method. Your code must be :

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Testing {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    String array1 [] = new String[4];
    array1[1]="Tom";
    array1[2]="Jerry";
    array1[3]="Mike";
    array1[0]="Dustin";
    System.out.println("the very first name is "+array1[calculatew()]+" The second name is "+array1[calculatew()]+" the third accodental name is "+array1[calculatew()]+" and the final random name is "+array1[calculatew()]+".");
  }

  public static int calculatew () {
    Random generator = new Random();  
    int number1 = generator.nextInt(3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the calculatew method definition inside of your main method definition, you cannot do this in java. Put them side by side and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Tour problem is exactly what the compiler is telling you. Change to 'calculatew()' within the brackets, and move the method definition outside of the main method.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is simply telling you that calculatew is not a variable. If you wish to use it as a method (as you are) you must type calcualatew(). The brackets tell the compiler that what has been typed is a method that must be called. If you remove the brackets the compiler sees it as a variable and cannot find it inside the variable stack nor as an object handle so it tells you that it cannot be found

--EDIT

Try using an IDE like [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) that tells you before you request for compilation if there is something wrong syntactically and points directly to the line and offers suggestions on how to resolve the issue
If you need help on using eclipse let me know in the comments